# Error while trying to download chromium onto my chrome book authentication error

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, chromebook

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 onto my chromebook using crouton (xfce4) and downloaded the software center (apt-get install software-center) however when I do into the software center to install chromium web browser there is an authentication error it states I do not have the required privileges `org.frerdesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name: ':1.64}): org.debian.apt.intsall-or-remove-packages`

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu you are using?

Comment: When typing in lsb_release -a the release is 16.04